# INT function not working and I'm trying to remove quotes from a list of numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, int

I am trying to generate a list of numbers that do not have the '' around them.  I have tried using the INT(x) function and the MAP function.  Neither have worked.  This is the code that is generating the lists:

```
for f in range (0, workingframes):

    if f<=(workingframes/2):

        for x in range (0, archnodes):
            frames[f].append(archstartred[x])
            frames[f].append(archstartgrn[x])
            frames[f].append(archstartblu[x])

        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop()
            archstartgrn.pop()
            archstartblu.pop()
            archstartred.insert(0, backred)
            archstartgrn.insert(0, backgrn)
            archstartblu.insert(0, backblu)

    else:
        frames[f]=frames[workingframes-f]

    [int(value) for value in frames[f]]
```

This is generating the correct numbers, I just need the quotes removed so that I can use the lists in another program.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide what `frames[f]` contains?

Comment: Note that `range(0, N)` is more easily written as `range(N)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list comprehension looks right (assuming `frames[f]` is a list of strings containing integer values), but you need to assign the resulting list to some variable so that you can use the result.

E.g.,

```
int_val_list = [int(value) for value in frames[f]]
```